# Condense ES2015/CommonJS Modules to One CommonJS Module with Gulp

Tags: node.js, typescript, gulp, commonjs, babeljs

I am writing an library in TypeScript that I want to compile into a single CommonJS module. With `browserify`, I could give it a single file, have that file run through `tsify` and `babelify` to produce one file that had all of the files combined into one. I basically want the same sort of functionality, but I need it to result in a CommonJS module to use with CommonJS-compatible systems like NodeJS instead of the browser.

I am having troubles finding an option or a plug-in that does this. Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is `--standalone` or `-s` option:

> Generate a UMD bundle for the supplied export name. This bundle works
>   with other module systems and sets the name given as a window global
>   if no module system is found.

**Using the Command Line**:

```
browserify main.js --standalone myLib > myLib.js
```

**Using the API**:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var b = browserify('./main.js');
b.bundle({standalone: 'myLib'}).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/myLib.js'));
```

Comment: That's close. Do you know if there is any way to get the default export to be registered directly? That approach requires users to do `let myModule = require("my_module").default;` to grab whatever is exported like `export default myModule;`

Comment: UMD(Universal Module Definition) is compatible with all three module loading systems: CommonJS, AMD or script tag in browser. Everything you export from a module will be availabe when you require the module using CommonJS.